# Extracting string from line, give as input to a command and then output the entire line with replacing the string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

1. I have a file containing like below, multiple rows are there

   ```
   test1| 1234 | test2 | test3
   ```
2. Extract second column `1234` and run a command feeding that as input
3. lets say we get `X` as output to the command
4. Print the output as below for each of the line

   ```
   test1 | X | test2 | test3
   ```

Prefer if I could do it in one-liner, but open to ideas.

I am able to extract string using awk, but I am not sure how I can still preserve the initial output and replace it in the output. Below is what I tested

```
cat file.txt | awk -F '|' '{newVar=system("command "$2); print newVar $4}'
```

#

Sample command output, where we extract the "name"

```
openstack show 36a6c06e-5e97-4a53-bb42
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Property                   | Value                             |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| id                         | 36a6c06e-5e97-4a53-bb42           |
| name                       | testVM1                           |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: In short, you want to replace 1234 on each line with the output of a command?

Comment: Yes, Can that be easily done on one liner while I print the content output ?

Comment: You should stop worrying about getting a "one liner" and instead just focus on getting a solution that's concise, robust, efficient, portable, etc. - i.e. satisfies all the criteria that actually matter for good software. The right solution depends on how large your input file is, how important speed of execution is, and whether `command` can take a whole list of values at once and produce the corresponding list of converted values, or if it's required to operate on 1 value at a time. So please provide more information in your question and give a concrete example of `command` so we can help.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - I would prefer to run it by two commands, I know its possible with your option, but I see you created a separate script

Comment: @sshark, Actually it is NOT a single script, it is multiple commands; you could see them in steps  information.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lF'/\|/' -ne 'chomp( $F[1] = qx{ command $F[1] }); print join "|", @F' < file.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`s
- `F` specifies how to split each input line into the @F array
- `$F[1]` corresponds to the second column, we replace it with the output of the command
- [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the trailing newline from the command output
- [join](http://p3rl.org/join) glues the array back to one line

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F ' *| *' '{("command "$2) | getline $2}1' file.txt
```

e.g.

```
$ awk -F ' *| *' '{("date -d @"$2) | getline $2}1' file.txt
test1| Thu 01 Jan 1970 05:50:34 AM IST | test2 | test3
```

I changed the field separator from `|` to `*| *` to accommodate the spaces surrounding the fields. You can remove those based on your actual input.

Answer (score 0):

If `command` can take the whole list of values once and generate the converted list as output (e.g. `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`) then you'd want to do something like this to avoid spawning a shell once per input line (which is extremely slow):

```
awk -F' *[|] *' '{print $2}' file |
command |
awk -F' *[|] *' -v OFS=' | ' 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0; next} {$2=a[FNR]} 1' - file
```

otherwise if `command` **needs** to be called with one value at a time (e.g. `echo`) or you just don't care about execution speed then you'd do:

```
awk -F' *[|] *' -v OFS=' | ' '{
    cmd = "command \047" $2 "\047"
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        $2 = line
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}' file
```

The `\047`s will produce single quotes around `$2` when it's passed to `command` and so shield it from shell interpretation (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and the test on the result of getline will protect you from silently overwriting the current $2 with the output of an earlier command execution in the event of a failure (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline). The `close()` ensures that you don't end up with a "too many open files" error or other cryptic problem if the pipe isn't being closed properly, e.g. if command is generating multiple lines and you're just reading the first one.

---

Given your comment below, if you're going with the 2nd approach above then you'd write something like:

```
awk -F' *[|] *' -v OFS=' | ' '{
    cmd = "openstack show \047" $2 "\047"
    while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        split(line,flds)
        if ( flds[2] == "name" ) {
            $2 = flds[3]
            break
        }
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, If I have my "command" having its own operations of awk. Example below command=openstack show <ID> | grep name | awk -F "|" '{print $3}'       Is it possible to use it within the awk block you defined above ?

Comment: Yes but it'd be the wrong thing to do. Let's assume `<ID>` in your comment is `$2` in the scripts disussed so far then you wouldnt embedd `openstack show <ID> | grep name | awk -F "|" '{print $3}'` within an awk script since `grep name | awk -F "|" '{print $3}'` is **shell** code, instead you'd set `cmd` above as `cmd="openstack show \047" $2 "\047"` and then write **awk** code to parse its output that getline reads into `line`.

Comment: I updated my answer to show a possible solution but I don't know anything about how `openstack` is called nor what it outputs so I'm guessing at the right approach.

Comment: Revised awk works well, flds[3] contains lot of spaces. Is there a way to trim it ?

Comment: Of course, it's only software, but all i had to go on was the command line you said worked for you and so what I wrote does just that same thing. I can't keep guessing at what we're trying to parse though - please edit your question to include examples of the command you're trying to execute (`openstack show <ID>`) and the output of that command and what you want to extract from that output to use in place of `$2` in the input file.

Comment: You can't put formatted text in a comment, See my previous comment and update your question

Answer (score 0):

This finally did the trick..

```
awk -F' *[|] *' -v OFS=' | ' '{
    cmd = "openstack show \047" $2 "\047"
    while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        if ( line ~ /name/ ) {
            split(line,flds,/ *[|] */)
            $2 = flds[3]
            break
        }
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}' file
```